# How to add component html in existing Angular component

Tags: angular, angular7

I have an app component in my angular application.

```
@Component({
    selector: my-container',
    template: `<div [innerHTML]="infoComponentHtml"></div>`
})
export class MyContainerComponent implements AfterViewInit {

    @Input() infoComponentHtml: string = "";

    constructor(private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver){

    }

    ngAfterViewInit(): void {
        if(this.infoComponentHtml){
            ??????
            append this.infoComponentHtml dynamically
        }
        else{
            ??????
            append "<default-content></default-content>" dynamically
        }
    }
}
```

`this.infoComponentHtml` format is like this `"<component-name></component-name>"`

`this.infoComponentHtml` is third party component that comes from another component. So I do not know the component class name of it.

How can I compile and add append the component?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use structural directive `*ngIf`:

HTML:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="showInfoComponent; else defaultContent">
    <infoComponent></infoComponent >
</ng-container>    
<ng-template #defaultContent>
    <default-content></default-content>
</ng-template>
```

UPDATE:

You cannot load components using `innerHTML`. In order to load components dynamically, you need to set component `infoComponentHtml` to `Type<Component>`;

```
@Input() infoComponentHtml: Type<Component>;
```

and then use [this answer to load component dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36325212/dynamic-tabs-with-user-click-chosen-components/36325468#36325468)

Comment: I need it AfterViewInit

Comment: I could not set the `<infoComponent></infoComponent>` from string. template parse error occured

Comment: @barteloma do you know the selector name?